# How not to use the adaptive icon feature for my app in Android?

Tags: android, icons

I have 2 games that I created, both compiled for Android.

I run both games on an Oreo device, but for some reason one shows the original icon and one shows the icon inside a white rectangle.

I am trying to find out how Android decides whether to show the original icon or the icon inside the white border as part of the adaptive icons feature.

Target API version? icon with alpha channel?

Comment: Seems like a very trivial issue.... Have you looked at the docs? https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html What's the issue with defining your own adaptive icon, so it's used across the board?

Comment: Have looked and read the docs. But the question is why is there a difference, in other words, what Android is checking in order to decide what kind of icon to use.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out how this works, so posting here for others that encounter the same problem.

Android uses the targetSdkVersion to select if the adaptive icons feature is used. If the targetSdkVersion is 26 and above, it will add the white border around the icon, if 25 or lower is used, it will not.

I guess what Android is doing is treating the icon image as the foreground element of the adaptive icon and using white as the background element.

The real solution here should be to support adaptive icons of course, but as a quick solution, I just changed my targetSdkVersion to 25 for now.